# Default interface implementation

Tags: java, android, interface

In Android, when I use `AsyncTask`, I usually use interface method, so that I can implement it in `activity`:

```
 public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Response> {

private Context context;
private DownloadTaskListener listener;
private List<MyObject> objectList;


public interface DownloadObjectsTaskListener {
    void startTask();
    void finishTask();
    void ObjectsDownloaded(List<Object> ObjectList);

    void withoutInternet();
}

public DownloadObjectsTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


public void setListener(DownloadObjectsTaskListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    if (CommonUtils.isThereInternetConnection(context)) {
        listener.startTask();
    } else {
        listener.withoutInternet();
        cancel(true);
    }
}

protected Response doInBackground(String... urls) {
    RestApiObject api2 = new RestApiObject();
    return api2.getMyObjects();

}

protected void onPostExecute(Response results) {
    listener.finishTask();
    if (results != null) {
        if (results.body() != null) {
            ObjectsResponse request = (ObjectsResponse) results.body();
            ObjectList = request.getObjectsList();
            listener.ObjectsDownloaded(ObjectList);
        } else {
            ResponseBody jsonObject = results.errorBody();
            try {
                Log.d(DEBUG, jsonObject.string());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(DEBUG, "result is null");
    }

   }
}
```

And then In my `Activity`, I implement the interface, and define the method.

The thing is for method such as `withoutInternet()`, the method definition will always be the same, so it will just be redundant code each time I redefine method implementation, even if I extract code in a method.

Is there a way to define just once `withoutInternet()`?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you want an `abstract` class instead of an `interface.` Like this:

```
public abstract DefaultDownloadObjectTasksListener implements DownloadObjectsTaskListener{
    abstract void startTask();
    abstract void finishTask();
    abstract void ObjectsDownloaded(List<Object> ObjectList);

    void withoutInternet(){
      //some default implementation
    }
}
```

And then you can `extend` (versus `implement`) the abstract class overriding the methods you want to provide functionality for. Because the first three methods are `abstract` you will be required to override them. However, because `withoutInternet` is not abstract, the default implementation will be used, unless you choose to override it.

**Edit** To address your issue:  the solution then would be to make your `DefaultDownloadObjectTasksListener` extend `AppCompatActivity` and implement `DownloadObjectsTaskListener` and then extend `DefaultDownloadObjectTasksListener` from your activity.

Or, really, what I would do is use an anonymous subclass as a listener if you really want a default implementation.

Comment: I can't extend the abstract class in my activity because activities already extend AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base activity that implements your interface, implement `withoutInternet()`, and declare the other methods as abstract. Your activities would then extend your activities from the base activity and you only need to implement the other methods.